# how to remove catalina.out from Linux server where Apache tomcat server installed

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have deploy JSP website on Linux base Apache tomcat server  Project size is approx 5 to 6 MB .But unexpected   Catalina.out file is auto generate its Size is 11 Gb i don't know how to fix it i don't want Gen-rate catalina.out I have search from  Google about this then i found

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE

to

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF
```

This should be changed But i dont know how to change this i have to Fix In Tomcat server Or in My Project please help me i am new and developed website first time this Major issue is coming please help me how to Fix it .

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to remove catalina.out file. You can use logrotate, to rotate logs, and remove old files.

Very useful description is here:

http://www.swoops.co.uk/how-to-set-up-log-rotation-for-tomcat-catalina-out-log-file/

or here:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-rotate-tomcat-catalinaout

Answer (score 0):

Never delete the `catalina.out` when tomcat is running.

If the `catalina.out` is deleted after `tomcat` is stopped, it will create a new `catalina.out` once `tomcat` starts again and it is totally safe.

But if you remove the `catalina.out` while `tomcat` is running, it will keep on logging to `catalina.out` which is removed already (reference of the file is hold by the `tomcat`) hence the space will not be released. So you will need to restart the `tomcat` sever to release the space. It is not recommended.

Actually you can clear the log of `catalina.out` file without stopping tomcat with the command below.

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

To keep `catalina.out` smaller, either one of the following ways can be used:

1. You could use the above `Linux` command and add it to a `CronScheduler`
   to run daily/ weekly/ monthly or yearly as preferred.
2. Use `logrotate` tool in `Linux`. It is a log managing command-line tool
   in Linux. This can rotate the log files under different conditions.
   Particularly, **we can rotate log files on a fixed duration or if the
   file has grown to a certain size.** You can click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rotating-logs-logrotate#:%7E:text=logrotate%20is%20a%20log%20managing,manage%20the%20matching%20log%20files.) for more
   info on this.